# Event-Driven Programming Paradigm in Logic Programing

Tags: event-handling, event-driven, logic-programming

I need to write a paper on the Event-Driven Programming Paradigm in **Logic Programing**. I have been able to find a lot of information on Event-Driven Programming in Object-Oriented and Functional programming, but not for Logic programing. I would appreciate some direction in respect to Event-Driven Programming in Logical Programing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event-driven programming should be similar to how it is done in other languages, you would set up some framework to generate the events and you would call a *goal* to handle the event, possibly using the system's multithreading facilities (which leads to interesting aspects of transactions on the Prolog database, global vs. thread-local storage etc.)

Paulo Moura would certainly provide this link to the Logtalk Manual:

- [Event-driven programming](https://logtalk.org/manuals/userman/events.html)

Also this paper comes to mind:

- [How agents do it in stream logic programming](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.62.7235) -  Matthew M. Huntbach , Nick R. Jennings , Graem A. Ringwood (1995).

Comment: This is great. Thank you!